# To drop some text onto a treeitem of treeViewer and further populate it into treeitem

Tags: java, swt, jface, drag-and-drop, treeviewer

I want to drag text from a tableViewer, drop onto a `TreeViewer`, and populate the dragged text into 
the selected treeitem. 
Drag source and drop target is set. The first encountered problem is that the item of `DropTargetEvent`
is `null`, so I can't know which treeitem text is dropped onto.

Code of drop method fro Drop target is as following:

```
public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
   System.out.println("Droped" + event);
   if (event.data == null) { 
     event.detail = DND.DROP_NONE;
    }
    //TreeItem item = (TreeItem) event.item;
   Tree xmlTree = xmlVisualEditor.getTree();  //to get the target tree
   Point selectedPoint = new Point(event.x, event.y);
   TreeItem item  = xmlTree.getItem(selectedPoint);    #<----- Null pointer exception

   if (TextTransfer.getInstance().isSupportedType(event.currentDataType)) {
      String dropedData = (String) event.data;
      System.out.println("Dropped Data:" + dropedData);
      item.setText(dropedData); 
   }
```

}

I print the content of drop target event, it shows as:

> DropTargetEvent{DropTarget {} time=141201730 data=students-name x=861
>   y=393 item=null operations=3 operation=1 feedback=1 dataTypes={ 13 1 }
>   currentDataType=13}

As it can beesen, item is `null`.

About next to do, I need to

1. get the treeitem where it is dropped.
2. populate the dragged text into one column of dropped treeitem

Any comments about approaching a solution is welcome. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For a `TreeViewer` you should extend `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerDropAdapter` and implement the `performDrop` method. Use `TreeViewer.addDropSupport` to install the adapter.

In `performDrop` a call to `getCurrentTarget()` will get you the target object.